# PHP - store and retrieve a password from/in an ini file

Tags: php, passwords, ini

I am building a simple device configuration assistant with PHP. The device will draw its configuration data from an ini file. Writing and reading array data to and from the file is no problem and works fine.
My problem is: A section of the file contains SMTP mail server data, including username and password. As soon as a password containing double quotes has been written to the file, reading from it causes an exception, naturally (assume `smtp_auth_pw="pass5"word"`: will cause `syntax error, unexpected 'w'`).

Using a database is no option. The only solutions seeming possible to me are:

- Base64-encode the password at the users client with JS, tell the OS software developers to decode it on their end (**Huge computation load on the client**)
- Base64-encode the password at the server with PHP, tell the OS software developers to decode it on their end (**Much complexity for a single value**)
- Escape all unsafe characters, tell the OS software developers to unescape them on their end (**Much complexity for a single value, possibly misunderstandings between devs**)
- Disallow unsafe characters to be used in passwords at all (**Uncomfortable restriction on users**)

Neither option seems favorable to me. Recommendations on how to handle unsafe strings in ini files?

Comment: There must be a defined syntax for ini files how delimiter characters can safely be embedded, no!? Something like `smtp_auth_pw="pass5\"word"`. Any sane "language" which uses "special characters" has this. If that's your only issue, figure *that* out. Don't go out of your way with encryption or hashing, which has nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: Any comment on the downvote, please? What do you think it'll help if I don't know why my question seems to be not useful/unclear or badly researched to you?!

Comment: @deceze PHP just reads the file line by line, escaping is possible but I'd rather not change the string itself. Hashing the string actually *has* to do with this, as it would eliminate all unsafe characters while keeping the content untouched.

Comment: Yes, hashing would solve *that* problem, but it opens the new problem that **then you have no access to the password.** If you want to represent a value in a "language" like ini, then you need to conform to the syntactical rules of that language. In this case, this means you need to escape your values correctly. The only time you won't have this problem is if you dump the password into a plaintext file and the password is the sole content of that file.

Comment: How so? A base64-encoded string can be decoded in almost any language, and is just a regular string value. This is not about securing the password! I just need a possibility to store a string containing any char in an ini file.

Comment: Base64 *encoding* is a completely different thing than *hashing* with, e.g., MD5. Yes, base64 *encoding* would be fine. Hashing would not be.

Comment: You are right, my fault, I meant encoding in contrary to hashing. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Escape all unsafe characters, tell the OS software developers to unescape them on their end

Yes exactly, that's what needs to be done. You're writing a file in INI format, which means you need to conform to INI syntax.

> (Much complexity for a single value, possibly misunderstandings between devs)

No, it's not complexity. Whenever you read data in a specific format (here: INI), you need to read it according to that format's specification, including any and all escaping rules. If you use a library to read and/or write that format, **these escaping rules should already transparently be considered** by that library. There should be absolutely no overhead in honouring INI escaping rules, and no misunderstandings between developers because that's standard practice for dealing with any and all specialised text formats.

Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a terrible idea to store passwords in a plaintext file, but that wasn't your question, so assuming you've considered the security risks, might I suggest using `urlencode()` which will convert chars like quotes and colons and is easily decodable with `urldecode()`

Comment: As this happens on an embedded linux with an encrypted filesystem, so I hope it should be safe enough, though I do not have a say in that anyway.
`urlencode` is a good idea though!

Comment: @MoFriedrich, I didn't downvote you, but that's probably why someone did. If your .ini file is on a public webserver then it doesn't matter if your system is encrypted. make sure you've `chmod`ed your .ini file to something like 700, or whatever works so that public can't request the file/.

Comment: @MoF You're not willing to escape the value according to ini format, but you're willing to URL-encode it...? :-/

Comment: @Adelphia, as I said, security is not my responsibility, the ini file lies outside of the public web root and the devices will only be used in local networks...

Comment: @MoFriedrich either urlencode/urldecode or base64 will work just fine for your purposes. give it a shot :)